# Multi-Threaded accessing same deque C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my multi-threaded application, I have two threads that use the same `std::deque`. One of them writes to it, while the other reads from it (for data analysis).

I get this error:

> Deque iterator not dereferencable

**EDIT:**
This is the code that I use for reading from the deque. The error is thrown somewhere deeper in the if-condition (where I'm accessing the deque with `at`).

```
for (int i = 0; i <myDeque.size(); i++){
    try{
        if (myDeque.at(i) > 10){
            //do stufff
        }
    }
    catch (...){
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
}
```

I assume, that this happens due to this multi-thread access of the deque.
I cannot catch the error with  a `try-catch` block. Can't I do this, because it's thrown in a deeper "plane"?
Is there a possibility to fix this error?

Comment: is the `deque` empty?

Comment: No, it is not empty.

Comment: Are you using any synchronization mechanism (such as a lock or mutex) to serialize accesses to the dequeue object?  If not, you should; that is the standard solution when you want multiple threads to be able to access a shared data structure.

Comment: `assert(!d.empty());` right before you dereference.

Comment: While you probably have a data race unless you also have some sort of synchronization mechanism, your problem is that you're using invalidated iterators. If one of your threads is writes to the deque while the other still is traversing it, your iterator becomes invalidated.

Comment: @bku_drytt: Writing doesn't necessarily invalidate. Insertion and deletion at the ends of the `deque` won't invalidate iterators unless the iterators are currently referencing the deleted element.

Comment: @ShadowRanger http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_back says that `emplace_back()` invalidates all iterators, same for `push_back()` and `push_front()`. Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: @bku_drytt: Looks like I forgot to link the reference I was using, which [is actually the same as yours, but for the `deque` itself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which claims: "insertion and deletion at either end of a deque never invalidates pointers or references to the rest of the elements." But I just realized that's slightly different from how I read it, since it says pointers and references aren't invalidated, but says nothing about iterators. Extra confusing since an iterator is largely used the same way as a pointer syntactically. Blech. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use locking? In some commonly accessible location, declare a [`mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex):

```
std::mutex deque_lock;
```

then wrap reads and writes to the `deque` in [blocks that acquire it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
... nondeque stuff ...
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(deque_lock);
    mydeque.push_back(...);
}
... more nondeque stuff...
```

and when reading:

```
... nondeque stuff ...
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(deque_lock);
    for (const auto& elem : mydeque) {
        ... do stuff with each element, ideally cheap things to avoid blocking writer ...
    }
}
... more nondeque stuff...
```

Try to keep the work to a minimum in the locked block; if it's expensive work, it may be worth copying out the value under the lock, then using it without the lock to avoid blocking the other thread.

Comment: What does the other thread do, when it wants to access a blocked memory. Is it stopped or does it simply go on and "drop" the operation it wanted to do on the deque?

Comment: @black It is blocked and waits until it can acquire the lock on the mutex in order to proceed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks! So I'll do this for the writing process (push_back). Should I do it for the reading, too? (For the for-loop in my question). I'll read 25 elements (in the example its only 10). Is this too long?

Comment: @black you would help yourself a lot if you understood some multi-threading concepts before you wrote a program using them. Have you considered reading a book on it?

Comment: @black: You'd use the same `deque_lock` around code that was reading the `deque`. The idea is that only one thread can own the `deque_lock` at a time, so whichever thread owns it has exclusive access until the lock is relinquished (which happens with the `lock_guard` is destroyed at the end of the block it's created and initialized in).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extremely simple example of a reader/writer pair communicating through a queue.

Note the use of a condition_variable to synchronise communication about whether there is work to do and whether the writer has finished (signalling that the reader can stop when it's emptied the queue):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable reader_action;
bool all_written = false;

std::deque<int> buffer;

// note: this function is called with the mutex unlocked
// we have popped i from the buffer
void handle_read_event(int i)
{
    if (i % 100000 == 0)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread writer([]{
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i)
        {
            {
                auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
                buffer.push_back(i);
                lock.unlock();
                reader_action.notify_one();
            }
        }

        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
        all_written = true;
        lock.unlock();
        reader_action.notify_one();
    });

    std::thread reader([]{
        while(1)
        {
            auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
            reader_action.wait(lock, [] { return all_written || (!buffer.empty()); });
            if (!buffer.empty()) {
                int i = buffer.front();
                buffer.pop_front();
                lock.unlock();
                handle_read_event(i);
            }
            else if(all_written)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    writer.join();
    reader.join();
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
0
100000
200000
300000
400000
500000
600000
700000
800000
900000
```

If we decide that we don't mind making the writer wait while we drain the queue, we could implement the second thread thus:

```
std::thread reader([]{
    while(1)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
        reader_action.wait(lock, [] { return all_written || (!buffer.empty()); });
        while (!buffer.empty()) {
            int i = buffer.front();
            buffer.pop_front();
            handle_read_event(i);
        }

        if(all_written)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

... or any other strategy that suits our purposes.

Comment: I would like to reduce the usage of mutex as less as possible, because i think `emplace_back()` operate at the first element of deque while `front()` and `pop_front()` operate at the first element of deque, they didn't access the same element. Then i modified your code to [this](https://onlinegdb.com/LeAPNzUu2), it seems works fine, but if change the `i` in writer thread from 100000 to 1000000, the output become abnormal that it print many zero, i don't know why

Comment: 1 you have to use a mutex because the container is not thread safe.

Comment: 2. Your concerns about performance are unfounded. Use of an an uncontended mutex is no more expensive than an atomic exchange.